# Morphisms of Affine Sets and Morphisms of Corresponding Coordinate Rings.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I stumbled across something that I really couldn't really figure out.

So suppose you have a morphism of affine algebraic sets: $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and the corresponding coordinate ring morphisms: $f': k[Y] \rightarrow k[X]$

Why is it equivalent to saying that $f$ is closed if any only $f'$ is going up?

I've been wondering this for the past couple of days and I just can't figure it out. Is there an explanation to this at all?

Comment: What do you mean by "$f'$ is going up"?

Comment: Well in this context. Suppose we have a chain of prime ideals, $P_1 \subset P_2 \subset .... \subset P_n$ of $k[Y]$ and a chain of prime ideals $Q_1 \subset Q_2 \subset ... \subset Q_m$ of $k[X]$. You can extend the prime ideals of $k[X]$ such that it covers all of the prime ideals of $k[Y]$ (and we have that $f'^{-1} Q_i = P_i$)

Comment: What did you already try? If you write out the definition of going up and a description of closed sets in the Zariski topology, then it should be clear where to go.

Comment: @MohamedHashi I think I figured it out for the backwards direction (where $f'$ is going up then $f$ is closed). But I can't figure out if $f$ is closed then $f'$ is going up. You say it's clear but I don't really see it.

Comment: Sorry, it is not so clear. Going up implies lying over, so if f' is going up then f must be surjective. There are closed maps that are not surjective. For example the inclusion of points. Ill write an answer tomorrow.

Comment: @MohamedHashi Thanks for the response. I'm still trying to figure out f closed implies f' is going up still.

Answer (score 0):

The map on coordinate rings will be denoted by $f^*$ instead of $f'$ .

Exercise 5.10 of Atiyah and Macdonald states that $f^*$ is going-up iff $f(V(\mathfrak{p}))=V(f^{*-1}(\mathfrak{p}))$ for all primes $\mathfrak{p}$.
This will be the main ingredient.

Assume $f^*$ to have the going up property.
Let $W\subset X$ be closed. 
Then $W=V(I)$ for some radical ideal $I\subset K[X]$.
It has a finite number of irreducible components $V(I)=\cup_{i=0}^n V(\mathfrak{p}_i)$. This gives
$$f(V(I))=f(\cup_{i=0}^n V(\mathfrak{p}_i))=\cup_{i=0}^n f(V(\mathfrak{p}_i))=\cup_{i=0}^n V(f^{*-1}(\mathfrak{p}_i)).$$

Hence $f(V)$ is closed as a finite union of closed subsets.

Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be any prime in $k[X]$. We always have $f(V(\mathfrak{p})) \subset V(f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}))$.
Let $f(V(\mathfrak{p}))\subset V(I)$ then $I\subset \cap_{\mathfrak{p}\subset\mathfrak{m}} f^{*-1}(\mathfrak{m})= f^{*-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ so $V(f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})) \subset V(I)$.

Assume that $f$ is closed, then $f(V(\mathfrak{p})) = V(f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}))$ by the previous. The result from A&M implies that $f^*$ has the going-up property.